# Make a 2 line ellipsis text fill max width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a 2 line ellipsis with english and japanese text.
The idea would be :

Row can have a max width of X pixels and min width of 0 px.
If any text in row don't require max space, then the width of the column is [0, X]
If text don't fit 1 line, then jump on second line.
If text don't fit 2 line, show ellipsis.

The problem I face is, with Japanese text, or text with character like `-` etc... the text just break directly, and never fill the max available space.

If I set a max available space, then the text do not jump on second line and is not dynamic (so can't be smaller if size of text don't require X px)

Is there some way to do this  without JS ?

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.special-td {
  max-width: 250px;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  width: ft-content;
}

.image {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 }
 
 .text-truncate-2{
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="special-td">
      <div style="display:inline-flex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/48x48">
      </div>
      <span class="text-truncate-2" > Leotica/キッズサロペットパンツ/ホワイト/90</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="special-td">
      <div style="display:inline-flex">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/48x48">
        </div>
        <span class="text-truncate-2" >234234-234234-234234-234234-2342234234</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like it's not work for any long string without spaces or another "separate" symbols. Try to insert in first cell some long string like "123123123123123....". It won't break in two lines with ellipsis

Comment: word-wrap: break-word; will break your line in any possible positions (space, tab, dash, e.t.c)